# 422 Error Code when sending a Post Request from Angular Frontend to FastAPI Backend

Tags: angular, post, fastapi

I send a Post Request from angular frontend to an fastAPI backend. but the Backend gives back an 422 error code.
Thats the Request:

```
 public submit(): any{
this.httpClient.post<any>(
  this.endpoint,
  this.data
).subscribe()
```

}

```
export interface FormLogin {
  readonly data: string;
}
```

And thats the backend:

```
    @app.post('/login')
    def create_login(login: Login):
    db.append(login.dict())
       return db

    class Login(BaseModel):
    data: str
```

Comment: check data you are posting is of type Login at backend.

Comment: The 422 error will contain an error message in JSON that tells you what field is missing or what validation fails. Include that error message in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will resolve your issue, just inform backend you are sending data in JSON format.**

```
 public submit(): any{
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.httpClient.post<any>(
        this.endpoint,
        this.data, {headers: headers}).subscribe((response)=> {
    });

}
```